# scrape the text from the website and build a data frame to import the information to the csv file

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio

This is the R code that I am using to scrape the text from the website. But I am not able to build a data frame, As I want to import the information to the csv file.

```
library(rvest)

scraping_source <- read_html("https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/the-cost-of-being-a-drug-addict-in-canada")


scraping_source %>%

html_nodes("h2")

scraping_source %>%

 html_nodes("h2") %>%

html_text()

scraping_source %>%

html_nodes("b")

scraping_source %>%

 html_nodes("b") %>%

html_text()
```

Comment: Share what your expected outcome would look like, given the data you scraped.

Comment: expected outcome should be somewhat like this                             
  Drugs                    Cost                                                                                                    1.)Cocaine       (cost of using it)                                                                 2.){second drug}    (Cost of using it)